# Any quick fix for playing 1 minute 20M byte MP4 videos served from Salesforce files without pauses in the playback?

Tags: lightning-experience, video

This is a question about streaming speed not about how to embed a video in the UI.

Accessing from Vimeo (who distribute their content via [Content Delivery Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) providers) a video will play continuously. Accessing from a locally added Salesforce org File, pauses in the playback happen.

Now I get it that Salesforce makes no claims to be a video content platform but we have a small amount of content that we would like to host in an org and that content includes some videos. Hosting the content in a separate domain raises questions about customer firewall policies.

There is documentation such as this [Experience Cloud Content Delivery Networks (CDN) Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_cdn_overview.htm&type=5) but I don't see direct mention of video content.

Has anyone successfully served video content with or without the CDN feature turned on?

Comment: I don't suppose re-encoding the video is an option, is it? 2.66 Mbps isn't bad if it's 1080p 60fps video, but if there are large portions of the video that aren't changing very often (like a Dreamforce presentation) it should be relatively easy to get a smaller encode (assuming you have access to a lossless or minimally compressed version). That, or perhaps encoding using CBR (constant bit rate), which would end up being a larger file but perhaps end up being delivered more smoothly (if the network is stable).

Comment: Hi @DerekF, I did try out Vimeo's "optimized" format that took one 18M video down to 2M. (That one was more of a slide show.) One other I tried changed very little. But I take your point that minimising the size of the content is a worthwhile step; just not sure how small in general I can get them and still have decent quality on modern fairly high pixel count screens. No expertise on video encoding I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not an expert on video encoding either, but I have a grasp on it and a beefy CPU. If this is something you can share outside of your organization, I could take a crack at it. DM me on twitter @derekfdev, or pop into the Open Office Hours chat ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53431/open-office-hours ). If you can't share the video(s), I could still probably help you through using Handbrake (a multiplatform GUI for encoding using x264, x265, vp8, vp9, or theora)

Comment: Hi @DerekF, A very generous offer - thank-you. I'll be in touch; certainly could use some advice on this encoding topic.